# Conditional Formatting in ExactTarget Personalized Subject Line

Tags: email, exacttarget

How can I setup conditional formatting using ExactTarget personalization? I want to only show the punctuation if the first name exists.

For example, if name exists subject is `NAME! Rest of Subject.` but if the name field is blank then `Rest of Subject.`

`%% first_name %%! Rest of Subject.` ends up returning `! Rest of Subject.` if my first_name value is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%%[
If Not Empty([first_name]) Or [first_name] != "" Then
    Set @salutation = Concat(ProperCase([first_name]),'! ')
Else
    Set @salutation = ""
EndIf
]%%
```

%%=v(@salutation)=%%Rest of Subject.

Notes:

- This assumes that the column with first name is "first_name";
- This assumes that the first_name column could come in as NULL or empty;
- The space that will appear after the exclamation point is in the variable;

Place this in the email, and in the subject line input field, insert: **%%=v(@salutation)=%%Rest of Subject.**