# Conditional rendering in exacttarget

Tags: rendering, conditional-statements, exacttarget

Does anyone know if it is possible to execute conditional statements in Exacttarget?

For example, if x variable === y, render image 1.

if x variable === z, render image 2.

This is fairly out there and the docs doesn't cover it, so I'm just crossing my fingers here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, its called Ampscript. You can do all your basic rules and lookups with this. [doc link](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/)

```
%%[IF expression1 <comparison operator> expression2 THEN]%%
    [wrapped script or email content]
%%[ELSEIF expression1 <comparison operator> expression3 THEN]%%
    [wrapped script or email content]
%%[ELSE]%%
    [wrapped script or email content]
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a relevant question on Stackoverflow:

[Conditional Formatting in ExactTarget Personalized Subject Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399160/conditional-formatting-in-exacttarget-personalized-subject-line)

Which lead me to find: https://help.exacttarget.com/es-US/documentation/guide_template_language/built_in_block_helpers/

Question answered! :)